# What is a "System Group"? Is there detailed security documentation?

Tags: permissions, gemini

Under Administration > Security > Global Groups the groups have an checkbox field labeled "System Group", what is this?

I can not find any references to this in the online documentation. Is there a more detailed document available for groups and permissions and how they related to projects?

Answer (score 0):

In Gemini 4.2 this option was used to indicate a group that could not be deleted. It was implemented to prevent people from accidently deleting core groups.

Obsolete setting in Gemini 5.x